# Creating a function in postgresql what return value to use

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, postgresql-9.3

I'm new to PostgresSQL programming and am trying to create a function called `update_docket` so that I can call it from an existing stored procedure.

With the help of some great StackOverflow folks I was able to build my update statement as follows:

```
UPDATE incode_warrants iw
SET    warn_docket_no = iv.viol_docket_no
FROM   incode_warrantvs  iwvs
JOIN   incode_violations iv ON iv.viol_citation_no = iwvs.warnv_citation_no
                           AND iv.viol_viol_no = iwvs.warnv_viol_no
WHERE  iw.warn_rid = iwvs.warnv_rid;
```

In Navicat (My Postgresql interface) I run this query on the database and I get a return message of Affected Rows with a count.

Now I want to take this query and build a function but I'm unsure as to what I should use as the return value.  I was guessing at int4, and I tried to build it with return value void but nothing seems to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to create this function so that I can call it from within a very large stored procedure?

I've looked at the Postgresql manual and am admittedly a bit confused and intimidated as I'm not much of a SQL guy.

I believe in the function I need a BEGIN and END for the transaction and I've even tried `return 1;` but so far I haven't had any luck in successfully saving this function.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: Unrelated but: you most probably do **not** want `incode_warrantvs` in the `from` clause. [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*"

Comment: @Bill Thanks for the link.  I've read through this but I'm still unsure as to what return type I need for this function.

Comment: Why not go with your gut and use int4? What breaks in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but I am not sure what code you are running. But, if you are doing a generic stored procedure in postgres, you could do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function([parameters to be used in stored procedure, if any])

RETURNS boolean AS -- [or you can have it return any data type such as integer]

$BODY$

DECLARE
    some_variable text;
    some_other_variable integer;
    another_variable timestamp;
BEGIN

/*
Put stored procedure here, in this case it would be your update statement
*/    

RETURN true; -- or you can return whatever you want based on what you declare above under RETURNS

END; -- closes the BEGIN clause

$BODY$ -- this is simply a delimiter to open and close the actual procedure that runs
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hopefully that gives you some idea.... But it would be helpful if you posted whatever you were trying to run.